# JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> does not seem to be working as exepected as JpaRepository<T, I>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Normally while using JpaRepository interface, I tend to mention the methods in the interface that I would be using in my service class. Example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findAll(); // Usually I mention the methods this way in the interface.

}
```

And this works perfectly. However, when using the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface, if I mention the methods in my interface, it throws error like - failed to create query method....

If I do not mention the method, it works as expected. Can someone explain this odd behavior in Spring, please?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    List<User> findAll(UserSpecification user); // If I do not mention this method here, it works perfectly.

}
```

Comment: Because the specifications encapsulate and replace the explicit condition you normally mention using the spring data "domain specific language" for repository methods. If you would have taken a look at the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) you would see that this interface already covers all these methods that you normally would write down explicitly.

Comment: But that is the case with JpaRepository<T, I> interface as well. And it still works.

Comment: Obviously not, JpaRepository only covers the basic cases

Comment: In JpaRepository interface, findAll() method is available in Jpa Interface, but after mentioning it explicitly, it still works. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `List<User> findAll()` is declared in one of the extended interfaces (namely  `JpaRepository<User, Integer>`). It's not an error to re-declare a method in an extending interface, provided the signature is the same; it simply has no effect whatsoever. This fact has nothing to do with Spring Data; this is simply how Java works.
2. `List<User> findAll(UserSpecification)` is **not** declared in any of the extended interfaces. Note that by virtue of implementing `JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>`, your interface will have inherited a method declaration with the signature `List<User> findAll(Specification<User>)`, which is **not the same**. Those two methods have different signatures, since `Specification<User>` is not the same type as `UserSpecification`.
3. You can, of course, add new methods to repository interfaces **as long as they represent simple queries**, without `Specification` arguments, e.g. `User findByName(String name)` and Spring Data will automatically generate implementations for those methods at runtime
4. You **cannot** add new methods to repository interfaces if their arguments represent custom types extending `Specification`, or any other types Spring Data cannot recognize, because at runtime, Spring Data won't be able to generate an implementation for such a method - it simply doesn't understand how to handle such a method

With specifications, you're supposed to use the methods that `JpaSpecificationExecutor` provides. I don't see why you would want a method like `List<User> findAll(UserSpecification user)`, either - if `UserSpecification` extends `Specification<User>`, then the inherited `List<User> findAll(Specification<User>)` will work just fine.